# Speedup Java regular expression

Tags: java, regex

I have a regular expression in java to extract certain urls from webpages I have crawled. These urls are basically javascript and stylesheets which get included into the pages. I have chosen to use a regular expression to extract these instead of parsing the document because this should be easier and parsing the document won't have any added value for me.

To get the valid urls (absolute or relative) I use the following regex:

```
([^"',\(]*)/endofurl
```

It extracts anything between '",( and the end of the url, in this example '/endofurl'.

Example:
[image]

The problem is that it isn't that fast (probably because of the ([^"',(]*) part).
Is there a way to speed this up by for example make it look for '/endofurl' part first and then go back until it reaches one of the start characters?

Comment: Can you show us some sample URLs?

Comment: It sounds like you have a more complicated mechanism than basic regex for extracting urls so you probably will need to code your mechanism/steps using regex for each step. i.e. step 1 first look for endofurl, then step 2 etc.

Comment: I think that regex alone is the wrong tool here.  You should be using an XML/HTML parser to grab the tags/nodes of interest.  After this, you can maybe use a regex on each isolated tag to validate the URL.

Comment: I don't think using a XML/HTML parser will help me because I also want the urls from embedded javscript etc. The only thing that it will to is breakup the document is smaller pieces.

Comment: How did you notice it isn't fast? Are you sure this regex is the cause of any slowing down? How do you use it in Java? Could you provide this code?

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to use regex for this.

Find the `/endofurl`:

```
int endOfUrl = s.indexOf("/endofurl");
```

Then (having checked that `endOfUrl != -1`) find the first occurrence of `"`, `,` or `(` before it:

```
int start = Math.max(  // Fictional version of Math.max which takes 3 inputs.
    s.lastIndexOf('"', endOfUrl),
    s.lastIndexOf(',', endOfUrl),
    s.lastIndexOf('(', endOfUrl));
```

Then (having checked that `start != -1`) extract the string:

```
String substring = s.substring(start + 1, endOfUrl + "/endofurl".length());
```

Then repeat from `endOfUrl + 1` to find the next occurrence, using the `String.indexOf(String, int)` overload of `indexOf`.

Comment: Thank you for your input, I will try your code on my mapreduce cluster and add the speed improvement to this comment when it is done.

Comment: This actually worked really good, it went from 2.5 hours to 4 minutes.

Comment: @thommie nice! Remember that regular expressions are built using basic string operations like this; so if you can express your problem using a few string operations, you will be at least as fast as the regex, and probably faster (as you found) because you don't have all the rest of the regex engine to, er, help you. It's a balance of speed vs readability/maintainability.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to speed this up by for example make it look for '/endofurl' part first and then go back until it reaches one of the start characters?

There's a truly horrible way that I can think of: search the string in reverse.

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("lrufodne/[^"',(]*");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(new StringBuilder(s).reverse().toString());
while (matcher.find()) {
  System.out.println(new StringBuilder(matcher.group()).reverse().toString());
}
```

I wouldn't recommend this, though. Easier just to use basic string operations.

---

An alternative would be to split the string on the characters you don't want, and look for strings containing `/endofurl`:

```
for (String part : s.split("[^\"',(]")) {
  int endOfUrl = part.indexOf("/endofurl");
  if (endOfUrl != -1) {
    System.out.println(part.substring(0, endOfUrl + "/endofurl".length());
  }
}
```

But, again, I'd go for more basic string operations: you don't really need to construct all the additional strings and the array here.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can change the regex to

```
"([\w.]*/)*endofurl
```

and use the complete match. This brings it down from 366 steps to 36 and also gives a (significant?) speedup.

[See it here at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/mTMUBk/1).